# Sound won't play from Python script

Tags: python, game-engine, audio

I get the error `AUD_FileFactory: File couldn't be read`. Other files from same path will work. Logic Brick works on the same file.

Using Blender 2.79 on Windows 7. Any ideas ?

Comment: The sample rate is 96K and file was created with Audacity. I have tried "WAV" and "MP3". Other 96K mp3 and wav files will play with a python script and windows media player. And the problem file will play when using logic bricks. I would think if the logic bricks will play the file, it isn't corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Without further information on the audio file it is hard to help. Since the error seems to originate from the file maybe just opening it in any audio manipulation software like audacity and exporting it in a known file type like wav appears to be the best option. Also, you will know whether your file is damaged if other software can't handle it either.